# Try-with-resources api pre 19

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It is possibly duplicate for [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290830/try-with-resources-are-not-supported-at-this-language-level-android) or [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498555/try-with-resources-android-studio), but for me its still not clear.
They say, try-with-resources supported from 19 api only, but refer to [that question](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36999599) its not so.

I have tested by my own with `Realm`.

```
boolean isClosed = RealmManager.isClosed(); //false here
try (Realm realm = RealmManager.getRealm()) {
     realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.where(User.class).findAll());
} catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
isClosed = RealmManager.isClosed(); //true here

public static boolean isClosed() {
    return realm == null || realm.isClosed();
}
```

And its works fine on 22 api (real phone) and 16 api (emulator).
So will that block work fine on pre 19 api on most phones and where is a truth?

I use `Retrolabmda`.

Gradle configuration:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *try-with-resources* at all API level using Android Studio 3.0:

> Android Studio 3.0 Preview 1 and later extends [support for try-with-resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features) to **all Android API levels**.

Also, you need to add annotation `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` to code block to hide warnings if you build your application for API level < 19. In case of this [annotation is not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45944802/3926506), you however can ignore warnings, build and run your application even if *try-with-resources* code block is highlighted as error.

Comment: Yes, i know. But now i use 2.3.3 AS and it still works.

Comment: But _try-with-resources_ is not supported on API level < 19 in AS version < 3.0. Solution trivial: upgrade AS or don't use _try-with-resources_ :)

Comment: Did you read my question?) It does work on pre 19 api even if its not supported as you say)

Comment: Of cource. I also read [_that question_](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36999599) where I found _Status:
Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)_. Why do you think it should work?

Comment: _even if its not supported_ - this is about AS 3.0 (not about AS 2.3.3), as well as whole my answer